# Is it possible to reference an dictionary from an item inside it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I've been trying to get a program to modify arrays containing an image item once said image is loaded.

```
images.push({
      image:new Image(),
      x:100,
      y:100,
      width:100,
      height:100,
      card:"2♠",
      visible:true})

let image = images[i]; //i is the value referencing the item pushed onto the main array
let img = image.image;

myFunction(img);

function myfunction(img) {
    //get image from img
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: Try what exactly? I've tried things like putting .super on the end, which obviously didn't work. But would've been annoying to find out was the answer.

Comment: Why didn't you post [the code of] your trials then? That would have given us more clues to answer your question. [Please read ...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method

```
function myFunction(img)
{
    const foundImages = images.filter(({image}) => image === img);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does find the image I was looking for. But it also manages to pick up the other images in the "images" array as well.

Comment: I think because I'm using new Image(), they're all identical

Comment: I do not know what img is and I do not know how your Image class looks like. So I can give you only the way you need to implement the details. Normally your image class should have a unique identifier you can filter for

Comment: This worked thanks, just needed to implement the === instead of =